# Owl Carousel "Synced" Infinite Loop

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I found this code on the internet but the problem is it is not infinite loop, what it does is if the last item displayed it rewinds back to first item. Is it possible to make it infinite?

Because if you have a hundred items on that carousel it might slow someone else device because of that.

Here is the synced demo
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/sync.html

Thanks

=============================

Code Below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

          var sync1 = $("#sync1");
          var sync2 = $("#sync2");

          sync1.owlCarousel({
            singleItem : true,
            slideSpeed : 1000,
            navigation: true,
            pagination:false,
            afterAction : syncPosition,
            responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
            autoPlay: 3000,
          });

          sync2.owlCarousel({
            items : 15,
            itemsDesktop      : [1199,10],
            itemsDesktopSmall     : [979,10],
            itemsTablet       : [768,8],
            itemsMobile       : [479,4],
            pagination:false,
            responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
            afterInit : function(el){
              el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
            }
          });



          function syncPosition(el){
            var current = this.currentItem;
            $("#sync2")
              .find(".owl-item")
              .removeClass("synced")
              .eq(current)
              .addClass("synced")

            if($("#sync2").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
              center(current)
            }


          }

          $("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
            sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
          });

          function center(number){
            var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;

            var num = number;
            var found = false;
            for(var i in sync2visible){
              if(num === sync2visible[i]){
                var found = true;
              }
            }

            if(found===false){
              if(num>sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
                sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length+2)
              }else{
                if(num - 1 === -1){
                  num = 0;
                }
                sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
              }
            } else if(num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
              sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1])
            } else if(num === sync2visible[0]){
              sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1)
            }
          }

        });
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but try to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345522/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-circular-infinite-carousel-using-owl-carousel?rq=1.

Comment: Thanks @MadalinaTaina, I mean when the last thumbnail is selected instead of looping the carousel what it does is scroll to the first thumbnail.

Comment: I like this owl carousel because it is responsive

Answer (score 0):

Please use the last version of the carousel and use **`loop:true`**: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/basic.html

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

html:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/136301/pexels-photo-136301-medium.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for the sync demo, where there is a thumbnail and image, seems like there is no solution to that?

Comment: @ChengeTheRules Put all your code here and I will help you with that. I really don't understand what is not working for you. Just add images...

Comment: when you reached the last slide and click next it rewinds back to the first one rather than continues loop :) Thanks again :)